# Convert Yaml properties object to Java object

Tags: java, java-8, yaml, lombok

Here is my Yaml properties file

```
bb:
  employees:
   -
    employee1:
      name: Syed
      locations:
        - HYD
        - MAA
   -
    employee2:
      name: Adhil
      locations:
        - BOM
        - DEL
```

I want to convert the object into my POJO in my applicaiton. However I'm not able to do it, it always returns null.

Is there anything which I'm missing?

```
@Data

@Builder
 @AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bb")
public class EmpConfig {

    EmployeeDetails employees;
}
```

### EmployeeDetails Class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration

public class EmployeeDetails {

    List<Map<String, List<String>>> details;
}
```

Comment: In configuration you use bb.employees, however in your Config class you use employeeDetails.

Comment: @Saphyra, updated the rquestion. However it returns same

Comment: _always returns null_ is not something we can understand. who, when, show stack trace, etc

Comment: There is no stackTrace :) EmpConfig.employees is simply null after service startup.

Comment: @Saphyra, there is no stacktrace because it returns null only, otherwise no exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked me this way:

The YAML (called application.yaml) (dashes removed before the employeeIds (employee1, employee2))

```
bb:
  employees:
    employee1:
      name: Syed
      locations:
        - HYD
        - MAA
    employee2:
      name: Adhil
      locations:
        - BOM
        - DEL
```

Config class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bb")
public class EmpConfig {
    private Map<String, EmployeeDetails> employees;
}
```

EmployeeDetails:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeDetails {
    private String name;
    private List<String> locations;
}
```

So basically you have problems with the syntax, and the data types, so Spring cannot parse the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me without modifying your structure.

YAML looks like:

```
bb:
  employees:
      employee:
        - name: Syed
          locations:
            - HYD
            - MAA

        - name: Adhil
          locations:
            - BOM
            - DEL
```

The output is

[image]

Hope it helps!